# Dropping the location pin on a place given the name/Google Maps URL?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have a MapView in my app, and I can load it without problems, with the Location Pin Dropped on a certain longitude and latitude.

Here is the code I used:

```
private MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap gmap;


    gmap = googleMap;
    gmap.setMinZoomPreference(17);
    UiSettings uiSettings = gmap.getUiSettings();
    uiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
    uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    LatLng ny = new LatLng(40.7143528, -74.0059731);

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(ny);
    gmap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ny));
```

It works well. The map loads and the gesture and enabled. The pin is dropped at the specified latitude and longitude as well.

However, I'd want to change this. I want the pin to be dropped based on the name of a place (Empire State Building, for example), or based on the URL (http://maps.google.com/?q=Empire%20State%20Building). However, upon spending time going around the internet and the documentation, it seems that the only way to set a pin is through a LatLng Object.

While I have no strong objections about using Lat and Long, I would prefer using the Identifiable Name or the URL of the place itself, as it would make the database easier to read.

Has anyone successfully set the pin using either the name or the Google Maps url?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can see is that to convert the name of a place to a lat-long using [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).

> Using Geocoding we will be able to convert address (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), and you can use that information to place the markers on map.